# Hair Counting Algorithm

Tags: opencv, image-processing, segment

I'm trying to implement an algorithm detecting and counting number of hairs. The main idea is described as below:

- Enhance Image by applying Contrast Stretching.
- Segment image.
- Do thinning segmented image.
- Detect Line by HoughLine Transform and Relaxation.

The implementation is based on Opencv/C++. However, since Thinning algorithm doesn't perform accurately, it leads to wrong result when I apply HoughLine, especially in case of overlap or touching hair. Moreover HoughLine is sensitive with parameters. If you have other ideas, please help me. Thank you very much.

[image: Orignal]
[image: Orignal]
[image: Orignal]
[image: Orignal]
[image: Orignal]
[image: Orignal]
[image: Orignal]

Comment: let me know when you figure out how many angels can dance on the head of a pin.

Comment: Actually, when counting, I just select a small area 80x80. Then, I do thinning and detect lines. You can see the updated image above.

Comment: why not detect the root of hair? arrea where hair (black) is almost enclosed by background skin color ? that would avoid problems with double counting crossed hairs ... If you got also the end of hairs you need to distinguish it (thickness or color of skin near it) also end of hair are usually in different height above skin so the focus is worse there which can be also detected sometimes

Comment: @Spektre, thank you for your idea. Each root area may has multiple hair, so how can I distinguish and count them.

Comment: I would first detect root position and then scan circle around it with some reasonable radius counting the hairs (or gaps) ... if hairs are sticked together this may introduce some error but far less then counting lines I think...

Comment: @NoiDoan,Have you able to count hair? I have same requirement can you please help me to calculate hair using OpenCv or others.